# Firebase Console still show Crashlytics Implementation Dialog

Tags: android, firebase, crashlytics, crash-reports

Implemented As Explained In Docs 
https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/get-started?authuser=0

```
buildscript {

repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.4'
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.1'
    classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.25.4'
    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
}
}
allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url 'https://maven.google.com/'
        }
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

**Module:app**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'

......
......
dependencies {
    ........
    ........

    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.3'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.3.2'
    implementation 'com.startapp:inapp-sdk:3.10.1'
    implementation 'com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.9.5'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crash:11.8.0'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

In Main Laucher Activity

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    /*StartAppSDK.init(this, getResources().getString(R.string.startApp_sdk), false);
    StartAppAd.disableSplash();*/

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_permission);

//Both Tried But Not get Any result

    Fabric.with(this, new Crashlytics());
   /*final Fabric fabric = new Fabric.Builder(this)
            .kits(new Crashlytics())
            .debuggable(true)  // Enables Crashlytics debugger
            .build();
    Fabric.with(fabric);*/
    FirebaseCrash.log("Activity created");
  }
}
```

I tried Manual Crashing

```
Crashlytics.getInstance().crash(); // Force a crash
```

My Problem Is Firebase Console still Showing Implementation Dialog

[image]

Why its already implemented since before 2 hours?

After crashing application logs looks like...for just testing Basb I removed my MainActivity from Manifest file. Error comes as expected but Firebase console is still showing implementation dialog. Why?

```
D/CrashlyticsCore: Crashlytics is handling uncaught exception "android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.gauravkhannamarketeer.navratriwallpaperapp/com.gauravkhannamarketeer.navratriwallpaperapp.activity.MainActivity}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?" from thread main
D/Answers: Logged crash
D/SensorManager: sensorCTSV isCtsVerifier false
                 sensorCTSV isCtsVerifier false
                 sensorCTSV isCtsVerifier false
D/CrashlyticsCore: No log data to include with this event.
D/CrashlyticsCore: Closing open sessions.
                   Closing session: 5BAB3C570014-0001-7C73-036ED06B5023
                   Collecting session parts for ID 5BAB3C570014-0001-7C73-036ED06B5023
D/CrashlyticsCore: Session 5BAB3C570014-0001-7C73-036ED06B5023 has fatal exception: true
                   Session 5BAB3C570014-0001-7C73-036ED06B5023 has non-fatal exceptions: false
D/CrashlyticsCore: Collecting SessionStart data for session ID 5BAB3C570014-0001-7C73-036ED06B5023
D/CrashlyticsCore: Collecting SessionUser data for session ID 5BAB3C570014-0001-7C73-036ED06B5023
D/CrashlyticsCore: Collecting SessionApp data for session ID 5BAB3C570014-0001-7C73-036ED06B5023
D/CrashlyticsCore: Collecting SessionOS data for session ID 5BAB3C570014-0001-7C73-036ED06B5023
D/CrashlyticsCore: Collecting SessionDevice data for session ID 5BAB3C570014-0001-7C73-036ED06B5023
D/CrashlyticsCore: Removing session part files for ID 5BAB3C570014-0001-7C73-036ED06B5023
D/CrashlyticsCore: Opening a new session with ID 5BAB3C9403A8-0002-7C73-036ED06B5023
D/CrashlyticsCore: Crashlytics completed exception processing. Invoking default exception handler.
```

Comment: Try removing depreciated dependency : `com.google.firebase:firebase-crash:11.8.0` and only use: [Crashlytics](https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/)

Comment: Thanks for Ur response but not working stll shows imlemetation dialog @ʍѳђઽ૯ท

Comment: How about updating google services? `classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.1.0'`

Comment: sure i will update it just sec

Comment: @ʍѳђઽ૯ท updated and run in vivo v7 plus real device but still shows implementation dialog

Comment: That's pretty weird. removing old `com.google.firebase:firebase-crash` and updating google services should do the trick. However, you can check from `Tools -> Firebase` and see if `crashlytics` is configured well and it says the same or not. Also, you can check [this sample](https://github.com/firebase/snippets-android/blob/ac6758a37a010c66ce251cd5834e279c2fd420b5/crashlytics/app/src/main/java/com/google/firebase/example/crashlytics/MainActivity.java).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By the way the main question is still going on but i solve it by moving to fabric implementation using android studio fabric plugin

**Fabric**

Download 'Fabric for Android' via your IDE repositories.
Mac users: Select "Preferences…" from the Android Studio / IntelliJ Menu.
Windows and Linux users: Select "Settings" from the File Menu.

Select 'Plugins' on the left side of the Settings Dialog. Select 'Browse Repositories...'

Search for 'Fabric for Android' and install the plugin.

After the IDE restarts, click the Fabric toolbar button to start using Fabric!

Comment: That is mess, don't use Fabric plugin. This is not any soultion. Only use Firebase console and follow instructions.

Comment: @user1209216  u are right sir but i followed instruction as fabric doc  explained